# Rails: querying associations during validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

During validation, I want to query associations but neither solution seems to be good because ActiveRecord’s style of validation. Here is an example:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :borrowed_books

  validate :should_only_borrow_good_books

  def should_only_borrow_good_books
    # What I want but it does not work:
    #
    # unless borrowed_books.where(condition: "bad").empty?
    #  errors.add(:borrowed_books, "only good books can be borrowed")
    # end
    #
    # ^ this query always returns an empty array

    # This approach works but it's not ideal:
    unless borrowed_books.all? { |b| b.condition == "good" }
      errors.add(:borrowed_books, "only good books can be borrowed")
    end
  end
end

class BorrowedBook < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  # attr: condition - ["bad", "good"]
end
```

One more option is to move the validation to `BorrowedBook` with something like `validates :condition, inclusion: { in: %w(good) }, if: -> { user_id.present? }` and perhaps validate association in `User` like `validates_associated :borrowed_books`. But I don't like this approach because it complicates things by moving the logic belonging to `User` to `BorrowedBook`. A few validations like this and your app might become really messy.

Comment: ActiveRecord lets you query columns from the database. To be able to call `borrowed_books.where(condition: "bad")` , `condition` should be a column in the borrowed_books table.  An `attr_reader`is not stored in the database.

Answer (score 0):

This validation should definitely stay in the user model. I do disagree that it will look messy if there are multiple conditions. If it makes messy, it often indicate that you should split the model or refactor the code there. It's the models job to enable you to access and validate the data from db. A way to improve the current code is to convert the condition column to enum, ref: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html you can write it like this

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :borrowed_books

  validate :should_only_borrow_good_books

  private 

  def should_only_borrow_good_books
    return unless books.not_good.any?
      errors.add(:borrowed_books, "only good books can be borrowed")
    end
  end
end

class BorrowedBook < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  enum status: [ :good, :bad ]
end
```